# maintaining a custom auto increment column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

I have a table with ID (identity) and XID (int) which is my custom auto increment column. I am using an instead of insert trigger to maintain XID, but I am getting duplicates.

---

**table**

xtable (ID identity, XID int)

---

**trigger** - instead of insert

```
insert into [xtable] (XID)
select [x].[NextavailableID]
from inserted [i]
cross apply
(
  select coalesce(max([t].[XID]), 0) + 1 [NextavailableID]
  from [xtable] [t]
) [x];
```

---

Assuming inserted = 1 row.

This trigger doesn't prevent duplicates in the XID column. Any ideas on how to change it?

Comment: Why do you need a second auto increment column? Is this a simplified example? There could be an alternative solution that is easier to maintain.

Comment: @GarethD - This is a simplified example. Each company needs to have a unique ID. So xtable would also have a CompanyID fk

Comment: Which SQL Server ? 2008 [R2], 2012, 2014 ?

Comment: @BogdanSahlean - updated version we are using, but any version solution would be fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating another table to store the last increment. In the trigger, inside a transaction, I select from the new table with hints (`UPDLOCK`, `ROWLOCK`).

---

**table**

```
Info (LastId int)
```

---

**trigger** - instead of insert

```
declare @nextId int;

begin tran t1

  set @nextId = (select top 1 LastId from Info with (UPDLOCK, ROWLOCK)) + 1;

  update Info set LastId = nextId;

commit tran t1

insert into [xtable] (XID)
select @nextId
from inserted [i]
```

---

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that where you have multiple rows being inserted you are using the same next available ID for all rows, you'd need to add `ROW_NUMBER()` in to ensure the xid was unique in the insert:

```
insert into [xtable] (XID)
select [x].[NextavailableID] + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY i.ID)
from inserted [i]
cross apply
(
  select coalesce(max([t].[XID]), 0) [NextavailableID]
  from [xtable] [t] WITH (TABLOCK, HOLDLOCK)
) [x];
```

With regard to preventing duplicates you can use table hints to lock `xtable` when getting the maximum `xid`.

The drawback of using these locks is that you will get deadlocking. You should have a unique constraint/index on this column as this will prevent duplicates, however it will also result in exceptions when a race condition is met. Ultimately, whatever method you choose you will need to make some kind of sacrifice.

Comment: Would this work if several insert statements were run in parallel?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear, I am assuming inserted was only 1 row.  I am getting the duplicates when multiple insert statements happen concurrently

Comment: @Aducci And that's why the answer was to use an `IDENTITY` column instead of a custom made one

Comment: Using holdlock I am getting the error message `transaction was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the victim`

Comment: The table hints idea was great. I just had to use them on a seperate table. Thanks for your help