# SQL Transactions with nolocks and TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, concurrency, sql-server-2012

I have a stored procedure like this.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[mysp] 
AS
SET NOCOUNT    ON
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED
BEGIN
BEGIN TRAN

DECLARE @TrackingCode INT   

SELECT @TrackingCode = DefaultsData 
FROM dbo.Defaults  
WHERE DefaultsID=77

UPDATE dbo.Defaults
SET DefaultsData = @PassedTrackingCode+1
WHERE DefaultsID=77

SELECT @TrackingCode

COMMIT TRAN
END
```

Assuming that we execute this stored procedure at the same time (concurrently) twice, what will be the `@TrackingCode` value that is returned at both the time. What if I used `NOLOCK` on the `SELECT` statement in the stored proc.

Comment: If you want that to behave in a predictable way you need to make the select with HOLDLOCK

Comment: You are using `READ COMMITTED` isolation level. It should be fine and I don't think you will get inconsistent result. run it and see yourself.

Answer (score 0):

1) If your intention is to generate unique tracking codes then it's a bad idea. You could do this simple test:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Defaults (
    DefaultsData INT,
    DefaultsID INT PRIMARY KEY
);
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.Defaults VALUES (21, 77);
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[mysp] 
AS
SET NOCOUNT    ON
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED
BEGIN
BEGIN TRAN

DECLARE @TrackingCode INT   

SELECT @TrackingCode = DefaultsData 
FROM dbo.Defaults  
WHERE DefaultsID=77

WAITFOR  DELAY '00:00:05' -- 5 seconds delay
UPDATE dbo.Defaults
SET DefaultsData = @TrackingCode+1 
WHERE DefaultsID=77

SELECT @TrackingCode -- Maybe it should return the new code

COMMIT TRAN
END;
GO
```

and then open a new window in SQL Server Management Studio (Ctrl + N) and execute (F5)

```
EXEC [dbo].[mysp]
```

and also open a second new window and execute (in less than 5 seconds)

```
EXEC [dbo].[mysp]
```

In this case, **you will get the same value**. `NOLOCK` is a bad idea (generally speaking) and in this case doesn't help you.

2) If (I repeat my self - sorry) your intention is to generate unique tracking codes then you could use

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[mysp] 
    @TrackingCode INT OUTPUT 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE  dbo.Defaults
    SET @TrackingCode = DefaultsData = DefaultsData + 1 -- It generate the new code
    WHERE   DefaultsID=77;
END;
GO
```

or you could use [sequences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24267505/maintaining-a-custom-auto-increment-column/24271109#24271109) (SQL Server 2012+).

Comment: I dont want to use unique tracking codes. I want for every user trying to execute the sp, a new tracking number needs to be generated and not identical tracking number.

Comment: but when the users concurrently execute this sp, they all get the same tracking number.

Comment: I think the second option you suggested would work. Will give a shot. Thanks Bogdan!

Comment: @user1176058: Yes. Your version can easily generate duplicated codes (see #1). Try my solution (see #2).